# Sub coordinate system in Actor

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

is it possible to use a sub coordinate system in an actor?

I'd like to implement a simple flat progress bar, that draws an filled rect according to the current state of the progress bar.

My problem:
If i add a progress bar to a stage, that has for example a FitViewPort(10, 10) and the progress bar has a size of 10 width and 1 height, i've only the posibility to display 10 different states of the progress bar:
[-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-].

Can i use a different coordinate system in the progress bar,for example 100x10, so that i can display 100 different states? The size of the progress bar should be defined in the stage's coordinate system 10x10.

Thanks
Mario

Answer (score 1):

the best solution will be to keep actor's **(x, y)** in some variabes and then calculate position on stage using `localToStageCoordinates`. Then you can also scale local coordinates. The following code is an example how to achieve it:

```
    Actor a = new Actor();

    //...

    float actorX = 0, actorY = 86;
    float xScl = 1, yScl = 0.1f;

    //... //modify inside-actor coordinates

    Vector2 positionOnStage = a.localToStageCoordinates( new Vector2(actorX * xScl, actorY * yScl )); //calculate stage coordinates fom local actor's
```